# InputType() doesn't translate from React Frontend to NodeJs backend

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, typegraphql

I am sending a query from a React component which appears like this (Apollo Client):

```
 const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(
        item.GET_ITEMS_QUERY,
        {
            variables: {
                first: 15,
                offset: paginateOffset,
            },
            errorPolicy: 'all'
        });
```

The GET_ITEMS_QUERY appears like this:

```
export const GET_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
query GetItems($first: Float!, $offset: Float!){
    getItems(query: {}, first : $first, offset : $offset){
       attribute1
       attribute2
       attribute3
       attribute4            
    }
}`;
```

I get the following error from the GraphQL server:

```
"Field "getItems" argument "query" of type "ItemsQuery!" is required, but it was not provided."
```

I can trace it down to this:

The GraphQL Resolver takes in 3 arguments, first and offset for pagination, and a query object of type ItemsQuery:

```
    @InputType()
export class ItemsQuery{
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    attribute1?: number;

    @Field({ nullable: true })
    attribute2?: string;

    @Field({ nullable: true })
    attribute3?: string;

    @Field({nullable: true})
    attribute4?: Date

}
```

I conclude that having just "query: {}" in the Gql String is not enough on its own when sent from the frontend. However, **if I go on playground and type in the exact same query, it works because there it's recognized as a ItemsQuery**. Would anyone know of a solution?

Thanks a bunch <3

Comment: I suspect if you look at the actual request in your browser's dev tools, you'll see the query being sent without the argument altogether. You can confirm it's a caching issue by editing the query (for example by changing the operation name to `GetItems2`) and checking the network tab again to see if it was updated.